# How to convert .doc, .docx, .ppt files into .pdf file using node

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, pdf-generation, doc

How can I convert .doc, .docx, .ppt files into pdf using node. I have searched a lot but could not find any free library available for converting doc files to pdf. I just want to convert .doc/.docx/.ppt files in .pdf files, I am looking for any open source API or Library for doing the same.

I found many paid API's but I want free tools. Any approach I can follow to achieve this.

Comment: "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers." - your question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this list module: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=word%20to%20pdf

Example: [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert), [awesome-unoconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-unoconv)

Comment: Both these plugins have a dependencies on libreoffice. I can't have such dependencies on my server. Is still there is any library or API which just convert word to ppt free

Comment: It is a very complex requirement you have.  The only free systems I've seen are based on Libre Ofifce/ Open Office or possibly on printer drivers.  Your comment above says word to ppt but I guess you still mean word to pdf.